# Фоновый скрипт массовой рассылки на 100.000+ адресов

Tags: php

Суть:
допустим, есть страница, где есть кнопочка "запустить рассылку". При её нажатии должен запускаться скрипт рассылки на 100.000+ адресов, который продолжал бы работу **при закрытии браузера** и всё такое. Желательно ещё чтобы как-то можно было увидеть процент выполненной работы на странице, где была кнопочка "запустить рассылку".

сервер, который в состоянии столько отправить, есть, с этим проблем не будет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в сторону чего смотреть. В гугле инфы не могу найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron вам в помощь
ЗЫ и да скрипт будет продолжать работу.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить скрипт сам в себе.

```
<?
... тут код отправки к примеру 10 писем чтоб уложиться в таймаут
    Также отмечать ящик на который уже отправлено письмо 'update mail set sttatus = 1 where id = $id'.
    При каждом запуске выбирать ящики на которые не отправлялось. Главное просчитать сколько писем максимум успевает отправится за отведённое время жизни пхп скрипта. Ну и в конце вызывать себя если в БД ещё остались ящики..

file_get_contents(mail.php);
?>
```

Comment: 1) мне не нужно укладываться в таймаут.
2) то ли я дурак, то ли лыжи не едут... разве так скрипт будет продолжать работать при закрытии браузера?

мне нужна именно фоновая работа.

Comment: вот погуглил что такое крон...
крон - планировщик, куда можно засунуть строку "запускать с такой-то периодичностью". Нигде не нашёл возможность останавливать через него. Наверно руки из задницы.

Можете объяснить как через него реализовать функционал (ещё раз распишу):
в админке кнопочка "старт". при её нажатии запускается скрипт "script.php". Браузер закрываем - он продолжает работать.
Открываем админку, жмём кнопочку "стоп" - скрипт останавливается.

Answer (score 0):

"в админке кнопочка "старт". при её нажатии запускается скрипт "script.php""

Самый простой способ:

Оный скрипт создаёт пустой файлик start.flag, наличие которого проверяется раз в секунду с помощью крона. Видим файлик -- запускаем рассылку, удаляем файлик.
Тоже для остановки.

Или так: http://linux.nedze.com/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-linux-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5/

Из ожидаемых проблем: попадание в антиспамерские базы, возможная блокировка хостерами и провайдерами. Короче вас будут принимать за спамера (но вы, ведь не спамер, да? ; ))

Вот ещё: http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2010/07/09/gearman-%D0%B8-php-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/

Comment: Блин, не понимаю немного принципа остановки...
допустим есть script.php

    while(1){
        echo '1';
    }

запустили мы его кроном. а как при нахождении файлика stop.flag этот script.php остановить? в кроне есть какая-то команда остановки процесса? мне бы ещё неплохо при остановке сделать некоторые действия (например сохранить последний использованный id куда-нибудь)

и, нет, я не спамер)) имеющаяся база - добровольные подписчики.

Comment: Вам не нужен цикл! Крон -- это процесс, который периодически запускает другие процессы. Вам нужно запускать скрипт проверяющий наличие файлов.
if start_file_exist { begin mega_list }
if stop_file_exist { stop mega_list }

Comment: Не, вы не поняли))
цикл - это просто вместо скрипта, который мне нужно запустить (рассылка по адресам).

меня интересует, как реализовать команду stop_mega_list. В кроне есть команда остановки процесса?

Comment: Тут всё очень зависит от... Вы же не непосредственно скриптом такие объёмы отсылать будете. Вы ж это какому-нить екзиму или постфиксу поручите...

Comment: http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2010/07/09/gearman-%D0%B8-php-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/

Answer (score 0):

Только сегодня сделал такое - импорт по 10 позиций большого файла.
Нужно рефрешить на javascript:
$counter = $counter-10;
window.location = script.php?counter=<=$counter?>;

Потому? что если делать header("Location:script.php?counter=$counter\n\n"); то это только 20 релоадов и потом браузер стопится.